# Load Tensorflow Model in Python 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a fully trained and saved Tensorflow model that I would like to load and use as a plug-in to a third party application ([UCSF Chimera](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/download.html)). This third party application  runs on Python 2.7 which does not support Tensorflow. If even possible, is there a way for me to use this model at all in python 2.7?

I was originally looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453361/run-a-tensorflow-model-without-having-tensorflow-installed) previous post but it was for Java/C++.

Answer (score 1):

First, save your Tensorflow model using `pickle`

```
with open("xxx.pkl", "wb") as outfile:
    pickle.dump(checkpointfile, outfile)
```

Second, install `anaconda` and create a python2.7 environment

Third, install tensorflow again in the python2.7 environment

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Fourth, read the model using `pickle`

```
pkl_file = open("xxx.pkl", "rb")
data = pickle.load(pkl_file, encoding="latin1")
```

Comment: Once I have the model restored as you described can I run my test data through it with the usual command:
`with tf.Session() as sess:`
`output = sess.run([op_to_restore], feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})`

Will this be acceptable once I have installed tensorflow using anaconda in the 2.7 environment?